# how to set logo on verifone vx520 internal printer

Tags: point-of-sale, verifone

I want to set a logo on printed paper in verifone vx520
should i change the <*PTRLGO> value? and how can i change the <*PTRLGO>?
and how can i download this logo to the printer? how should i call the logo on program? I have written my program with c.
here is my code but it's wrong. i used GP command to print a logo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <svc.h>

char myLOGO[]="testlogo.bmp";
char buf[200]="";
void main ()
{
    int i,t;
    char logo[]="*PTRLGO";
    char buf[500] = "";
    int prt_handle,prt_com;
    prt_handle = open(DEV_CONSOLE, 0);
    prt_com = open(DEV_COM4, 0);
    put_env(logo,myLOGO,1);    
    sprintf(buf, "%cGP1;",27);
    write(prt_com, buf, strlen(buf));
    SVC_WAIT (100);

    close(prt_com);    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to mess around with `*PTRLGO`.  Instead, use the "Font Tool" to generate a logo file from a bitmap.  Here's how:

1. Open the tool and go to File -> Import.
2. Navigate to your MONOCHROME bitmap (the 520 only has a monochrome screen, so this limitation shouldn't be a concern).
3. Choose "Save As" and change the type to "ITP Logo Files (*.lgo)".
4. For "Select Printer", choose Verix 37xx and click OK.
5. Be sure to remember to download the new logo file to the terminal.

NOTE on #4: The 3740, 3750, 3730/510, 570 and 520 all use the 37xx print pak, as far as I'm aware.

Now you have the logo file downloaded to the TERMINAL'S memory, but the terminal's PRINTER has its own memory, and you have to load it there before you can tell the printer to actually print it.  Here's some code that should work:

```
void PrintLogoToPaper()
{
    //open a printer handle and a file handle
    //Assume we have already acquired the printer from DevMan if you are using VMAC
    int hPrinter = hPrinter = open(DEV_COM4,0);
    int h_font_file = open("logo.lgo", O_RDONLY);

    //send the logo to the printer's memory
    p3700_dnld_graphic_file (hPrinter, h_font_file);


    //Now that we have loaded the printer logo to the printer's memory, 
    // we can tell the printer to actually print it out
    p3700_print_graphic(hPrinter, 0, 50);

    //remember to close your file and handles
    close(h_font_file);
    close(hPrinter);

    //Not sure why, but if you take this print message out, then the logo 
    //doesn't always print. Please update if you know a better solution.!
    clrscr();
    printf("Printing");
}
```

If you have done everything correctly, you should be able to print the logo out:

[image: StackOverflow Logo printed on Vx520]

Comment: how to download logo to TERMINAL's (by which command) and how to define p3700_dnld_graphic_file and p3700_print_graphic functions ?

Comment: These functions are defined in printer.h which is part of the ACT libraries.  `#include printer.h`.  As for how to download the logo file to the terminal--just treat it like any other data file.  (If you need more help with that, then please ask it as a new question since it's really a totally different topic).

Comment: I included printer.h but in compile an error occurred  undefined symbol p3700_print_graphic (referred from test.o) and undefined symbol p3700_dnld_graphic_file (referred from test.o) how can i correct this error?

Comment: Sounds like a linking error to me. Do you have your own printer.h file that it may be getting confused with? Can you find this function if you open the file from the ACT library?

Comment: no i use printer.h that's in ACT library and i found p3700_print_graphic function on it but  when used vrxcc command to compile the program and get .out file the undefined symbol error occurred

Comment: Are you successfully using anything else from the ACT libraries? I'm assuming you are using a make file, yes?  Do you have a `-I` for

Comment: (Sorry--my previous comment was unfinished and I didn't edit in time...)  Do you have `-I$(EVOACT)include` as part of it?  Are you also linking in the ACT library (`$(ACTLibraries)\act2000.a`)?  Also note the syntax should be `#include <printer.h>` (with brackets).  If you need more help with this, please ask a new question since it is a new topic and answering in comments is a bit difficult.

Comment: I use my own printer font in 32-columns per line but when i want to draw line with 32 underlines ( _ ) underlines don't feel whole of the line and between each underline it's take space. Do you know why and how can i fix it? I check in font generation tool and underline feel the whole of the horizontal pixels in 3th row.

Comment: Good morning to what you mean by "use the 37xx print pack", I follow the steps at the letter but I can not print anything, the only question is the offset parameter that you put in 50, and in the Font Tool app it puts me my icon in 0. I also put it in 0 but it does not print anything. any help I will thank you